# converter for xls to sql converter

Tags: php, converters

Am looking converter for xls to sql converter .

Or

Is There any script for insert from xls spread sheet to table ,

Regards

Bharanikumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your xls file to a simple csv file, and then use the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement.
Type "help LOAD DATA" in your SQL client to get more help on this statement.

Comment: Do not convert to sql, convert to csv, and use the load data infile statement.

Answer (score 2):

Excel data does not have Schema information by default. I came across an online tool recently that allows conversion from Excel to MySQL:
http://xlstosql.brightants.com/

**Input**:

Excel (xls / xlsx) file which contains data (has some specific format, you will have to check on the documentation for that)

**Output**:

A .sql export file (which can be imported into a MySQL database)
Works pretty well for me.

The other option that worked fine, was using the CSV intermediate. Excel can export to CSV and MySQL can import CSV via LOAD command or PHPMyAdmin. But I have to add the column, data-types manually every-time, and seems a slower option to export to CSV before.

Is there any Excel based plugin that can do this directly?

Answer (score 0):

Simply

1. copy paste your excel contents into openoffice spreadsheet
2. Save the spreadsheet
3. Import spreadsheet into phpmyadmin by selecting Openoffice document spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Save your .xls/.xlsx file to .csv file then parse it line by line then use `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )` with `;` as `$delimiter`